# Does the down payment for selling chomets have to be a percentage of its value

Tags: halacha, money, chametz-leaven, selling-mechirat-chametz

Today many large stores sell their chomets with a down payment of less than a .001 percent of its value.
Is this kosher? The Kitsur has a shtar mechiras chomets with different values of the down payment for the chomets and for where it is kept.
This suggests to me that what is called a pruta isnt good enough but the down payment has to have some relation to its value.
Also I doubt if any secular court would consider this a mechira. 
If one buys a property for 'millions' one doesnt give cents as a down payment: seemingly, chomets would be no different.

Comment: When I buy house the earnest money is around $1,000. The value of the house does not seem to matter.